# Setting Active State on mapped component

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a mapped component which iterates through API data. It passes props to each one and therefore each card looks different. See example below.

https://gyazo.com/39b8bdc4842e5b45a8ccc3f7ef3490b0

With the following, I would like to achieve two goals:

When the component is selected, it uses state to STAY SELECTED, and changes the colour as such to lets say blue for that selected component.

I hope this makes sense. How do I index a list as such and ensure the colour and state remains active based on this selection?

See below.

The level above, I map the following cards using these props.

```
                  {
                    jobs.length > 0 && 
                    jobs.map(
                      (job) => 
                      <JobCard key={job.id} job={job}
                      />)
                  }
```

I am then using the following code for my components:

```
const JobCard = ({ job }) => {


  const responseAdjusted = job.category.label
  const responseArray = responseAdjusted.split(" ")[0]

  return (
    
      <CardContainer>
        <CardPrimary>
          <CardHeader>
            <CardHeaderTopRow>
              <Typography variant = "cardheader1">
                {job.title}
              </Typography>
              <HeartDiv>
                <IconButton color={open ? "error" : "buttoncol"} sx={{ boxShadow: 3}} fontSize ="2px" size="small" fontSize="inherit">
                  <FavoriteIcon fontSize="inherit"
                    onClick={()=> setOpen(prevOpen => !prevOpen)}/>
                </IconButton>
              </HeartDiv>

            </CardHeaderTopRow>
            <Typography variant = "subtitle4" color="text.secondary">
              {job.company.display_name}  
            </Typography>
          </CardHeader>

          <CardSecondary>
          </CardSecondary>
        </CardPrimary>
      </CardContainer>
  )
}

export default JobCard
```

Comment: What is `setOpen` in `JobCard`?

Comment: Sorry anton! Worth mentoning that is state for a favourite button. Feel free to ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a state in the wrapping component that keeps track of the current open `JobCard`.

```
const [openCard, setOpenCard] = useState()
```

and then pass this down to job card together with a function to update.

```
jobs.map(
  (job) => 
    <JobCard 
      key={job.id}
      job={job}
      isSelected={openCard === job.id}
      onSelectCard={() => setOpenCard(job.Id)}
    />)
```

So now you can format your JobCard differently depending on `isSelected`, and run `onSelectCard` when the card is pressed.

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for this. I'm quite new to this concept so i'm trying to wrap my head around it. I can get the app to pass a handleClick when selected of your standard 'selected', but i'm not sure how to link to the job.id as you have stated. 
How would you pass the part with onSelectCard? That's what i'm struggling with.
```
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('you have selected me')
    onSelectCard
  }


  return (
    
      <CardContainer>
        <CardPrimary onClick={handleClick}>
```

Comment: hope this tags you! Sorry

Comment: When the function passed as `onSelectCard` is run, it will set the value of `openCard` to the `job.Id` of that `JobCard` since we pass in `job.Id` to the function. `() => setOpenCard(job.Id)`. Is this what you are after?